# How to force pandas.DataFrame.apply on a grouped DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

The behavior of `pandas.DataFrame.apply(myfunc)` is application of `myfunc` along columns.
The behavior of `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply` is more complicated.  This difference shows up for functions `myfunc` such that `frame.apply(myfunc) != myfunc(frame)`.

I would like to group a `DataFrame` then apply `myfunc` along columns of each individual frame (in each group) and then paste together the results.  There are hacky ways to do it, but I wonder it seems like there is some simple kwarg I'm missing.

Consider the example below:

```
In [22]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(5), 'b': range(5, 10)})

In [23]: df
Out[23]: 
   a  b
0  0  5
1  1  6
2  2  7
3  3  8
4  4  9

In [24]: def myfunc(data):
             # Implements max in a funny way.
             # However, this is just an example of a function such that 
             # myfunc(frame) != frame.apply(myfunc)
             return data.values.ravel().max()

In [25]: df.apply(myfunc)
Out[25]: 
a    4
b    9

In [26]: df.groupby(df.a < 2).apply(myfunc)
Out[26]: 
a
False    9
True     6
```

As you can see, `myfunc` was called like `myfunc(group)`.  This default behavior is reasonable, since `myfunc` takes in a `DataFrame` and returns a number, but this is not what I always want.  Is there a canonical way to force `myfunc` to be applied along columns of each group, as in `group.apply(myfunc)`?  The best I can come up with is an awkward wrapper:

```
In [27]: def wrapped(frame):
   ....:     return frame.apply(myfunc)

In [28]: df.groupby(df.a < 2).apply(wrapped)
Out[28]: 
       a  b
a          
False  4  9
True   1  6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
In [25]: df.groupby(df.a<2).aggregate(myfunc)
Out[25]: 
       a  b
a          
False  4  9
True   1  6

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

But this is simpler

```
In [26]: df.groupby(df.a<2).max()
Out[26]: 
       a  b
a          
False  4  9
True   1  6

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me:  df.groupby(df.a < 2).aggregate(myfunc) returns DataFrame({'a': [9, 6], 'b': [9, 6]}, index=[False, True]).  In other words, it did myfunc(g) (for g == a group) rather than g.apply(myfunc).  The docstring for aggregate specifies that it tries both of these, but does not specify the order in which they are tried.  Also note that myfunc is an example, so although .max() solves this case, I am still searching for an answer.  I am on version 0.12.

Comment: [@Ian Langmore](http://stackoverflow.com/users/993872/ian-langmore), change the return on your `myfunc` to: `return data.max()`. You don't want to `ravel` the two columns (you want them separate).

Comment: max was just a silly example.  I know that max is applied columnwise.  I'm looking for the more general answer that does not use pandas special implementation of max.  In other words, I'm looking for a canonical way to use a more general function (myfunc) that gives different results when applied to a frame as a whole or columnwise.  In other words, I want to consider functions such that myfunc(frame) != frame.apply(myfunc).  I want to force the behavior of frame.apply(myfunc) in a grouped frame.

Comment: then just iterate (and maybe concat, you'll have to handle that yourself), e.g. ``concat([ myfunc(grp) for g,grp in df.groupby(...) ])``